# Can I publish my flutter app with darts null safety feature enabled in production

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, publish, dart-null-safety

I have read in multiple [articles like this](https://medium.com/flutter/null-safety-flutter-tech-preview-cb5c98aba187#:%7E:text=Because%20we%27ve%20successfully%20migrated,with%20a%20small%20Flutter%20sample.&text=You%20need%20to%20pass%20an,t%20publish%20any%20migrated%20packages) or [this official dart documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety) that flutter developers should try the null safety feature in dart.

Yet we are not supposed to publish our production app with the null safety feature. The first article linked above (emphasis mine):

> Flutter experimentation with technical preview 2: This is today. Because we’ve successfully migrated the core Flutter framework to null safety, you’re able to try null safety to learn the new language feature and experiment with a small Flutter sample. If you’re a package author, you may also be able to do a trial migration, if you have a small dependency set that’s already been migrated by us. You need to pass an experiment flag, **shouldn’t use it in production**, and shouldn’t publish any migrated packages.

Therefore my question is following:

1. Are we able to publish flutter apps which have the null safety feature enabled?
2. Are there any huge disadvantages someone should be aware of, if he/she wants to publish his/her flutter app with the null safety feature (Besides the problem that null safety is not 100% bug prove)?

Comment: "Yet we are not supposed to publish our production app with the null safety feature." - Where did you see or read that you are not supposed to do that? Can you quote where you read that?

Comment: Sure this is from my first link from Michael Thompson: Flutter experimentation with technical preview 2: This is today. Because we’ve successfully migrated the core Flutter framework to null safety, you’re able to try null safety to learn the new language feature and experiment with a small Flutter sample. If you’re a package author, you may also be able to do a trial migration, if you have a small dependency set that’s already been migrated by us. You need to pass an experiment flag, shouldn’t use it in production, and shouldn’t publish any migrated packages.

Comment: I have published flutter apps since December 2018 with null safety. Both Android and iOS, never heard of such a thing of this. Even Kotlin and Swift provide this feature way before Flutter

Comment: can I upload my app which is not in null safety?